# prevent a form to be submitted multiple times - django

Tags: django, session, session-cookies

I am submitting a form. After that i am doing `HttpResponseRedirect` so that the form wont be submitted if one i refresh the page. BUT, if i `go back` in browser and submit the form again, the form will be saved multiple times. How can i prevent this?

I thought of session, meaning i set a session name like this:

```
if request.session.get('saved', False):
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/already_saved/')    
entry.save() # <-- pseudo save
request.session['saved'] = True
```

but this causes that the user can never send another form in my page in his actual session.

how can I create unique sessions for each form, so that one form doesnot get submitted multiple times but it is still possible to submit another forms?

Comment: You can add an expires header to the page with a time in the past (-1) and the page will not be valid when using the back button.
Using a session cookie to store it will work too.

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823580/django-form-resubmitted-upon-refresh

Comment: @PatrickBassut i dont have problems on refresh, i have problems with go back button. but thanks anyway

Comment: Do you want the user to not submit the same data twice, or to not submit the same data in a given short time?

Comment: @PatrickBassut not to submit the same form again - no matter in short time or how many times..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approach would be making a hash of the form's field and when the server receives the request you check if the hash of the form is already there (e.g. form already submitted). Something like this:

```
import hashlib
from django.shortcuts import Http404
sha512 = hashlib.sha512()
sha512.update(form_fields_stringfied)

if not request.session['forbidden_data']:
    request.session['forbidden_data'] = []

hashed_form = sha512.hexdigest()
if hashed_form not in request.session['forbidden_data']:
    request.session['forbidden_data'].append(hashed_form)
else:
    raise Http404
```

where hashed_form is the form data concatenated or in anyway you like

thus, no two forms considered equal will ever be submitted

Comment: @doniyor what about it ?

Comment: how do I hash the value and set to some field if the form is coming from clientside?

Comment: I don't understand. The session variable remains as long as the user finishes the session. And the form shouldn't have any relationship with the hash directly. The hash is a server-side thing that we did to check if the form is duplicated. That's all.

Comment: i think, i am thinking in a wrong way. you are right, session is the best way to solve this.

Comment: Yes. A bit different code but the same phlisophy as yours. :)