# Django form twice clicking SAVE got twice identical entries

Tags: django, forms

I have normal Django form. As I had a short server delay after pressing the "save" button of my form, I just clicked once more and Oops I have the entries twice in the database.

So my question: I am wondering whether there exists an mechanism which by pressing the save button several times prevents that identical entries are created?

Is a possible solution really hashing the entries like in this post:
[prevent a form to be submitted multiple times - django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23326873/prevent-a-form-to-be-submitted-multiple-times-django)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe it can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823580/django-form-resubmitted-upon-refresh

Comment: I have a `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('customer_subs', args=[pk]))` in my views.py, but seems that it does not solve the problem.