# Django: Refreshing page resubmits form

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I am facing one weird issue while using Django. I can see two entry of the video I am submitting in the database as the page where I am submitting the form refreshes automatically after submission (that is okay to refresh, as I can see the updated results in the table).

But the problem is while refreshing it resubmits the form. And if I manually refresh the page also it keeps submitting new videos. After doing some research I've found articles which leads to the problem in views.py in the application.

There is a similar question as well but the way they did I am not sure how to integrate with my view as I am returning some args to the page too. (Reference article: [django form resubmitted upon refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823580/django-form-resubmitted-upon-refresh))

Below is the code which I already understand less.

```
# Uploading videos form
    if not request.method == "POST":
        f =  UploadForm()   # Send empty form if not a POST method
        args = {"profile_data": profile_data, "video_data": video_data, "form": f}
        return render(request, "home.html", args)

    f = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES) # This line is to upload the actual user's content.
    if not f.is_valid():   # Q: Why do we need to check this? And if we do then is the right place and way to do it?
        args = {"profile_data": profile_data, "video_data": video_data}
        return render(request, "home.html", args)

    process_and_upload_video(request)
    args = {"profile_data": profile_data, "video_data": video_data}
    return render(request, "home.html", args)
```

Comment: That is why in case of a valid form, you should use a **redirect**, not rendering a response.

Comment: I am just checking if the form is not valid. So do you mean that I should check "else" condition too? Where I can do redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue when you *render* a response for a given successful POST request. Normally one uses the [**Post/Redirect/Get** [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern here: in case the POST is successful, you redirect to the view, such that the browser makes a new **GET** request, and thus will not resubmit upon refresh, like:

```
    # Uploading videos form
    if not request.method == "POST":
        f =  UploadForm()   # Send empty form if not a POST method
        args = {"profile_data": profile_data, "video_data": video_data, "form": f}
        return render(request, "home.html", args)

    f = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES) # This line is to upload the actual user's content.
    if not f.is_valid():   # Q: Why do we need to check this? And if we do then is the right place and way to do it?
        args = {"profile_data": profile_data, "video_data": video_data}
        return render(request, "home.html", args)

    process_and_upload_video(request)
    return redirect('some_view')
```

Where `some_view` is usually a listview, or the same view to enable submitting a *new* entry.

Note that you probably should *refactor* the above code: you here use a lot of *negative logic*, which makes it rather complex.

There are also some *odd* patterns in your code: for example you process the video in the view itself, which is typically *not* a good idea, since if this takes a lot of time, the request will timeout. Typically one uses *asynchronous tasks* (for example with RabbitMQ) to do timeconsuming processing, see for example [this article](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/20/how-to-use-celery-with-django.html).

The `form.is_valid()` is typically used to check if all required elements are in the `request.POST` and `request.FILES` (required fields and files, are these fields valid ones, etc.). A `ModelForm` adds some extra programmer convenience to convert the request into a model object.