# Confirm Form ReSubmission in django

Tags: html, form-submit

[image: if i refresh page this is popup]

**How to hide this message, automatic click in a continue or cancel**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823580/django-form-resubmitted-upon-refresh), which is very close to your question. In conclusion, you need to use a return HttpResponseRedirect, even if you are only redirecting to the same view.

More related question from Stack Overflow please click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833914/how-to-prevent-the-confirm-form-resubmission-dialog).